# Compare Sentry with Google Error Reporting

Tags: error-handling, sentry, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, error-reporting

I'm trying to see if we can replace Sentry with Google Error Reporting for unhandled errors in the production stage but when I research to compare the 2, not much came up. Even on stackoverflow, it doesn't seem like there's a related topic. Does anyone have any insight? Our application runs on Google Cloud services and we use Google Logging and Monitoring so it only makes sense to use Error Reporting over an external service like Sentry. Any information will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you already have them in sentry, my recommendation is to keep it in sentry.  GCP errors leave a lot to be desired IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentry has more features for sure but that only matters if you plan to use them. If Google Error Reporting gives you everything you need and you think it's quicker or easier for you to integrate with then just use that. If you end up missing some features in the future which you would have had with Sentry then you can always switch back to Sentry again.